# How can I use Moq to test my Index action that returns list from the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, moq, mstest

I am learning to use unit testing and Moq for ASP.NET MVC 5. I am trying to write my first unit test for the index action of one of my controllers.

Here is the code for the index action.

```
[Authorize]
public class ExpenseController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: /Expense/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Expenses.ToList().Where(m => m.ApplicationUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()));
    }
}
```

All I want to do is just check that the returned view is not null

Something like this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ExpenseIndex()
    {
        // Arrange
        ExpenseController controller = new ExpenseController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Of course, this is not working because of the connecting to the database and the using of the `ApplicationUserId` so would you guys help me to moq and unit test this action or recommend me a tutorial where I can get familiar with mocking in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Abstract the dependency to the database/dbcontext and then you can mock that into the controller

Comment: @Nkosi Would you please provide me with more information. Thank you.

Comment: Your controller has a hard dependency on the `ApplicationDbContext` which makes it difficult to mock in your unit test. You are going to need to refactor your dbcontext to inherit from an abstraction that exposes the functionality of the dbcontext and then you have the controller depend on that abstraction instead of the concretion. from there you can use a DI framework to inject the dependency into your controller and now you also have the flexibility to replace the abstraction with a mock implementation in your tests if need be

Comment: Hopefully this is not your real controller.  That `.ToList()` is basically a `select * from [Expenses]` that will pull the entire table into your server then filter in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to <strike>abstract</strike> encapsulate the dependency in a virtual method, for example: Create a virtual method that returns the user expenses, now your controller should look like:

```
public class ExpenseController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: /Expense/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(GetUserExpenses());
        }

        protected virtual List<Expense> GetUserExpenses()
        {
            return db.Expenses.ToList().Where(m => m.ApplicationUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
    }
```

Then, create a stub class, that is derived from your controller, and override the GetUserExpenses() method. It should look like:

```
public class ExpenseControllerStub : ExpenseController
    {
        protected override List<Expense> GetUserExpenses()
        {
            return new List<Expense>();
        }
    }
```

Now in your unit test, create the instance from ExpenseControllerStub  not from ExpenseController, and it should work:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ExpenseIndex()
    {
        // Arrange
        ExpenseControllerStub controller = new ExpenseControllerStub();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

This is how to do it manually. If you need to use a mocking framework for this, you will need to make GetUserExpenses() public not protected, then make a setup to return an empty expenses list, something like:

```
var mock = new Moq.Mock<ExpenseController>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetUserExpenses().Returns(new List<Expense>());
```

But I don't prefer to make this method public! may be there is a way for Moq to configure/setup protected methods, but I am not aware of it.

Edit: <strike>A more better solution is to totally abstract the Expenses repository, in this case mocking it will be straight forward.</strike>

Another solution is to inject the DbContext to the controller constructor, and use a mocking framework to mock it and the Expenses DbSet. You can find a sample for doing this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx)

Edit#2: You may also use [TestStack.FluentMVCTesting](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.FluentMVCTesting/blob/master/README.md) or [MvcContrib.TestHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.TestHelper/) to make you MVC testing easier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it will solve the current problem, but it is not really a practical solution. I am currently reading about how to abstract the repository as you mentioned at the end if you could help with that, I would be so grateful :)

Comment: No, this is a very practical solution, especially when you are working with legacy code. This may be the simplest one of the few things you can do then. Repository implementation has many variations - depending on your needs- and EF already implements a generic repository for you (DbSet). Anyway, I've updated my answer with an external link for how to mock DbContext and DbSet